# A closed contained in an open set

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff first countable topological space. Fix a countable decreasing local base of open neighborhood $(U_n:n\ge 1)$ of a point $x \in X$.

> **Question.** Is it true that there exists always an integer $n$ and a closed set $F$ such that
>   $$
> U_n \subseteq F \subseteq U_1\,\,?
> $$

Answer (score 0):

**Too long for a comment.**

Your question is equivalent to the existence of some $n$ such that $\overline{U_n}\subseteq U_1$,[ which in turn is equivalent (due to the decreasing nature of $U_n$) to $\partial U_n \subseteq U_1$.]

Now if $X$ is a topological group, then the claim is simple. Indeed, by the continuity of the addition, you can find an $n$ such that $U_n+U_n \subseteq U_1$. Then we have
$$\overline{U_n} \subseteq U_n+U_n \subseteq U_1$$

The same idea of proof works if the topopology is metrisable, and I suspect also if the topology is given by an uniformity.

Comment: Nice observation :) however, if the topology is metrizable, we can't use the continuity of the addition, so what's the analogue? It seems even easier because, in that case, we can speak of open and closed balls of explicit radious..

Comment: The essential point here is that the space is regular (also called $T_3$).

Comment: @Nduccio In that case you can show that for each $\epsilon, \epsilon'$ we have $\overline{B_{\epsilon}} \subset B_{\epsilon+\epsilon'}$. As for Uniform spaces, if you pick an entourage $U$ which corresponds to the open set $U_1$, you can find another entourage $V$ such that $V_{\circ}V \subset U$, and pick some $U_n$ "contained" in $V$ then $\overline{U_n} \subset U_1$. To me this proof is similar to  $\overline{B_{\epsilon}} \subset B_{2\epsilon}$.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, if $X$ is regular, then the answer is yes. But there are counterexamples in general.

The half-disk topology on $ℝ × [0, ∞)$ is a classical example of a Hausdorff non-regular space (https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000070). It is also first-countable. Now if we take just the subspace of rational points, i.e. $ℚ × ([0, ∞) ∩ ℚ)$, we obtain a countable space that also inherits all the properties mentioned above.